# Can you find which part of drupal handles form submit automatically?

Tags: php, drupal

No matter where the form is submited, the submited handler is called.

Anyone knows this?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Answer (score -1):

yourdrupalinstall/includes/form.inc: drupal_get_form()

It's being recognized by the form_id.